# convert nested array to JSON string in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, angular

I have a set of array like this : `[["Sarah"],["Jamie"],["B"],["148"]]`

and I want to convert this into **JSON string** with specific  element for each vaues. For example,

```
{ "name":"Sarah", "grade":"148", "School":"B"...}
```

How should I proceed? I tried to toString the array then bind with this element but it doesn't work out well..

**Original Json**

```
   "Data":{
      "Table":[
         {
            "Name":[
               "Jamie"
            ],
            "School":[
               "A"
            ],
            "grade":[
               "99"
            ]

         },
         {
            "Name":[
               "Mike"
            ],
            "School":[
               "B"
            ],
            "grade":[
               "148"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I was initially getting an JSON object from web-service. I had to some parse, and got the specific values for each of names but now I have to return it with names.. does it make sense? For example {"Sarah": "1", "Jamie": "59", "Mike" : "3"..} then parsing

Comment: What is the angular part ? If there is none, please remove the tag

Comment: @Xufox - updated in post. Thanks. Not sure below answer  by Ori Dori  is the best way to work for me.. I know that will work but Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you really need to nest each number string in another array? Just ["1", "2", "3", "4"] would be simpler.

Comment: I don't need to.. but that's what I get at the end..

Comment: But more importantly, is there always going to be a single element in those sub-arrays? I.e. is `[["1"], ["2", "3"]]` impossible? And is each value (number string) unique or is something like `{"Sarah": ["1"], "Mike": ["1"]}` possible?

Comment: srry, ill get back in a moment

Comment: Other than using replace method to remove inner brackets.. I have no clue.

Comment: You need to take original json parse it to an array of names, and an array of numbers, update the numbers, and then combine it back to an object?

Comment: my apologizes, i updated my original json object. I think it should be like that. That's exactly what I wanted to do. I was getting specific values to display in frontend, but now I want to bind with specific element names..

Comment: Okay, now that you’ve changed your requirements completely, what exactly are you looking for? An array of objects? Because you can’t have two `grade` or `School` properties in the same object. Also, why is `grade` spelled in lower-case? And why exactly does that first array hold both the names and the grades redundantly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the simple `forEach`

```js
var data =   {"Data": {"Table": [{"Name": ["Jamie"],"School": ["A"],"grade": ["99"]},{"Name": ["Mike"],"School": ["B"],"grade": ["148"]}]}};

var items = [];
data['Data']['Table'].forEach(function(item){
  items.push({name: item.Name[0], grade: item.grade[0], school: item.School[0]});
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to do this!

```
let newData = data.Data.Table.reduce(function(arr, obj) {
    let newObj = {};
    for (let key in obj) {
        newObj[key] = obj[key][0]
    }

    arr.push(newObj);
    return arr;
}, [])
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/500eo2gp/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want all array to be retrieved into JSON string. I want only values returned to be JSON string with each of names. For now, I only returned [["Sarah"],["Jamie"],["B"],["148"]], so I just want JSON string for this arrys along with their element names. Just like this [ "Name" : "Sarah", "Name" : "Jamie", "School":"B", "Grade" : "148"] and ignore rest

Answer (score 0):

```
let newDataArray = this.data.Data.Table.reduce(function(arr, obj) {
  let newObj = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    newObj[key] = obj[key][0]
  }

  arr.push(newObj);
    return arr;
  }, []
);
newData =JSON.stringify(newDataArray);
```

---

`JSON.stringify(newDataArray)` array from tymeJV 's code snippet will give you the JSON string as follows.

`[{"Name":"Jamie","School":"A","grade":"99"},{"Name":"Mike","School":"B","grade":"148"}]`

Demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wPhVTOFhRgERLXKCuoYl?p=preview